# WebSocket in Background transfer and NSURLSession in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, websocket, xamarin.ios, nsurlsession

I am looking into creating a Xamarin.iOS app that can connect to a WebSocket server when the app is backgrounded or suspended. The app is expected to close the channel once it receives a certain 'close' message from the server.

As per Apple's documentation, [NSUrlSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession) allows to [create a WebSocket task for the provided URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/3181171-websockettaskwithurl).

Xamarin has a short guide about using [NSUrlSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-walkthroughs/background-transfer-walkthrough), but the API reference documentation [does not have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsurlsession?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) any WebSocket-related methods.

A search engine search for 'xamarin nsurlsession webSocketTaskWithURL' returns zero results.

Is it possible to use WebSocket in NSUrlSession in Xamarin.iOS?

---

Update 1:

Visual Studio does not know anything neither about `NSUrlSessionWebSocketTask` nor about `.CreateWebSocketTask`:

[image: NSUrlSessionWebSocketTask in Visual Studio]

(Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017, version 15.9.25, Xamarin iOS 12.4.0.64)

Comment: You could check the code in the link below. It use the websock to connect. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653553

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT this does not answer my question. I already know how WebSocket in iOS works.

Answer (score 0):

Like the link i provided in the comment, you could use `NSURLSessionWebSocketTask` to make a URL session task that communicates over the WebSockets protocol standard.

```
  NSUrlSessionConfiguration nSUrlSessionConfiguration=null;
        NSUrlSession session= NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(nSUrlSessionConfiguration);
        NSUrl nSUrl =new NSUrl("");
        NSUrlSessionWebSocketTask task = session.CreateWebSocketTask(nSUrl);
```

Comment: I just tried to implement it as per your recommendation in a basic Xamarin Forms app. Visual Studio does not know anything neither about `NSUrlSessionWebSocketTask` nor about `.CreateWebSocketTask`, I am updating the original post with a screenshot.

Could you please point to the Xamarin documentation where `NSUrlSessionWebSocketTask` and `.CreateWebSocketTask` are specified? I cannot seem to find it in the official documentation.